What is the difference between nominal resolution pixels and raw pixels?
I've just read on this page of the Keyboard Maestro application that one should be aware of the difference between raw pixels and nominal resolution pixels when setting our Keyboard Maestro macros.
As it is the first time I've heard about it, I want to know if there was anything interesting to know besides the fact a typical Retina screen will have half as many nominal resolution pixels as raw pixels?

It will have a quarter of the pixels -- half as many on each axis.
